# Синтаксис PHP, работа с датой

Tags: php, дата

Нашел на просторах интернета такую функцию,
помогите разобраться с синтаксисом ее вывода:

Не смог найти описание в каких случаях используется оператор **new** и не ясно что делает конструкция **$base->add**

```
function get_easter_datetime($year) {
$base = new DateTime("$year-03-21");
$days = easter_days($year);

return $base->add(new DateInterval("P{$days}D"));
}
```

Заранее спасибо=)

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте основы PHP

> Для создания экземпляра класса используется директива `new`.

`$base->add(...)` вызывает метод `add` класса `DateTime`

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: понял, буду разбирать, до этой части не дошел еще, спасибо)